# Datalist paging with linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, datalist

I'm creating a page that uses Linqfor data access and I'm using DataList to display data.  How can I use Linq to do data paging  ? Please read simple code below :

I normally use a PagedDatasource but this only seems to work with a DataTable.

Here's my Linq to return Datatable which is bound with Datalist :

Public Shared Function GetStudentList() As DataTable

```
    Dim db As New DemoDataClassesDataContext()

    Dim query = From st In db.students _
                Order By st.st_studentid Ascending _
                Select st

    Dim dtStudent = New DataTable("myst")


    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_id", GetType(Integer))
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_userid", GetType(Guid))
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_studentid", GetType(Integer))
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_firstname", GetType(String))
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_lastname", GetType(String))
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_gender", GetType(String))
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("st_email", GetType(String))


    For Each q In query
        dtStudent.Rows.Add(New Object() {q.st_id, q.st_userid, q.st_studentid, q.st_firstname, q.st_lastname, q.st_gender, q.st_email})
    Next

    Return dtStudent

End Function
```

In the code behind of the page :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub LoadData()
    dsStduent = da_Student.GetStudentList()
    dt_Student.DataSource = dsStduent
    dt_Student.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will find the methods [.Skip() and .Take()](http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2007/10/04/linq-to-sql-paging-data.aspx) very useful.

I noticed you provided some code from your project, so here's an update on how you should implement these methods.

In your method for getting the data, do the following:

```
Dim query = (From st In db.students _
            Order By st.st_studentid Ascending _
            Select st).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize)
```

Then provide the `CurrentPage` and `PageSize` variables as arguments to the method. (You don't want to build them into the data access, as they could vary across different parts of your site...)

Comment: How to identify if the data has reached it's max limit i.e. we are on last page ?

Comment: Worked through some combinations. Now it is working for me. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at [SQL Paging with LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2007/10/04/linq-to-sql-paging-data.aspx) using the Skip() and Take() methods.