# Creating a DetailsView Pager in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, paging

My application has 10 products that are listed on a products page. When a user clicks one of these products they get directed to the details page for that product.

I would like to implement a next/previous pager on the details page that takes you to the next or previous product without having to go back to the products page.

I am assuming I have to write strongly typed view data that returns both the Product object as well as identifiers (SKU in this case) for the next and the previous product based on the product selected.

```
public class ProductViewData
{
    public Product product
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string NextSKU
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string PreviousSKU
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The question is, how do I get to the previous and next identifiers using LINQ in a efficient way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might need to do is pass in the entire list of SKU's to the details page through a session object.

The details page would load up the clicked item, via the query string of course.

Then you would have a Next / Previous button.  When clicked, they would need to figure out what items are next/previous based upon the current item in the details view.

So basically load your items into a session object.  You can do this when the "gallery" page loads, or when a user clicks on the actual link.

```
  private List<Item> ListOfItems{
        get { return Session["items"] as List<Story>; }
        set { Session["items"] = value; }
    }
```

then in your details view, find the currentindex and then the previous and next index.

Obviously you'll also need to account for hiding the prev/next button when the index gets out of bounds. but this is a start.

```
public ActionResult Details(long? id) {
    List<Item> items = ListOfItems;

    using (Entities df = new Entities ()) {
        Item i = df.Item.FirstOrDefault(st => st.ID == id);
        int currentIndex = items.FindIndex(st => st.ID == id);

        Item prevItem = items[currentIndex - 1];
        Item nextItem = items[currentIndex + 1];
        ViewData["previous"] = prevItem.ID.ToString();
        ViewData["next"] = nextSItem.ID.ToString();
        return View(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, there's no need to write a LINQ statement for this.  There's an MVC-compatible control for this called JQGrid that will do the job.  http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: I should point out, however, that you WILL have to make your model data json-compatible in order for this to work--that is how the control knows how to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` Extensions to `IEnumerable`:

```
var out = customers.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 3).Take(3).ToList<Customer>();
```

...then you can use `out1` to target the middle one. You might also want to cache `customers`. This form actually comes from [another stackoverflow.com answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764364/datalist-paging-with-linq).

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a pagenumber since I am not doing paging. All I have is a SKU number and I have to query the database for that SKU to display details as well as get the SKU of the product before and after.